# Your app may break after April 30, 2015

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a Facebook App only for development and tests. Its status is "not public" in the "Status & Review" page. This means that the app is offline and only accounts registered in the app can access it.

The app requests the following permissions to the registered users: email, public_profile, user_friends, **user_photos and user_videos**. For public apps, the last two permissions (user_photos and user_videos) need to be approved by Facebook. This process is part of the Login Review described [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login). Whenever an user logs in the public app that didn't pass by "Login Review" process, the login page presents the message "Your app may break after April 30, 2015. Some of the permissions below have not been approved for user by Facebook. Submit for review now or learn more."

However, I am a little bit worried because my app is not public and even so it is showing the same message. **Is the "Login Review" process necessary for non public apps? Non public apps can break after this date too?**

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If only users with a role in the App (Admin, Developer, Tester) are using the App, you don´t need to go through the review process at all. Just ignore the message.

Comment: Great! Is this true even for public apps?

Comment: depends. if you want ALL users to be able to use user_photos and user_videos, you need to go through the review process with those permissions.

Comment: I have a similar problem. If I understand correctly, I should split my app in two. A private one, which will be used only by the app admin and by developers, with all the extended permissions I want; and a public one with only basic permissions, for the purpose of enabling Login with Facebook for all users. Is that the best course of action? Also, can you cite any Facebook source about users of a private App keeping their extended permissions?